# Runtime error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

```
public static DataTable getDataTable(string retrievalQuery)
{
        sConn = new SqlConnection(AppSettingsExpressionBuilder.GetAppSetting ("DatabaseOG_VREG1").ToString());

        DataTable dtRet = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter sDA = new SqlDataAdapter(retrievalQuery, sConn);

        try
           {
             sDA.Fill(dtRet);
           }
             catch (Exception ex)
           {

           }
              return dtRet;

}
```

What could be the problem to this code? 
System.InvalidOperationException: The application setting 'DatabaseOG_VREG1' was not found in the applications configuration. Error Message is "The application setting 'DatabaseOG_VREG1' was not found in the applications configuration."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out appSettings section your web.config/app.config. It should have an element with that key.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="DatabaseOG_VREG1" value="some connection string" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

most probably the DatabaseOG_VREG1 key is missing in the appsettings section in config file